# Start own termianl tool as an argument of an command

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, command

I am currently developing a terminal tool which analyse the output of an command. 
I write the tool in python.
Now I would like to start my tool as an argument within every command, example: `python program.py -analyse`

In this case, `python program.py` is the command and I would like to start my own project `anaylse.py` with the argument `-analyse` which analyse the output from the project and writes its own output to a file. Now my question:

How do I get to start my own program `analyse.py` from the argument `-analyse` and how can I catch and read the output from `python program.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding -analyse as an argument will pass it to program.py.  I don't think that is what you are looking for.  I think you are looking for `python program.py | python analyse.py`.  Then just read the output from stdin.

Throw `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of analyse.py and change the permissions to executable to make it simpler yet: `python program.py | analyse.py`

Answer (score 0):

[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is the standard library module for dealing with command line arguments. I'd advise that you structure your script arguments in the following way:

Choose a character, say `f`, to indicate the name of the script you wish to run through your tool. This would be called in the following way:

`python program.py -f analyse.py`

Then you can use `argparse` to simply execute the file specified after the `-f` argument and do whatever you wish with the output.